# PHP snmpset error

Tags: php, snmp

So I'm trying to turn on a digital output from a denkovi SNMP ethernet controller in php. According to php manuals this should work but it doesn't. So here's my code if anyone can help me:

```
<?php
  if( $_GET["host"] && $_GET["port"] && $_GET["com"] && $_GET["oid"] && $_GET["status"])
  {
     $host =  $_GET['host'];  //localhost
     $ip = gethostbyname($host);
     $port =  $_GET['port']; //10161
     $community = $_GET['com']; //private
     $relenr =  $_GET['oid']; // 10
     $status =  $_GET['status']; // 1 (turn it on)   
     $adress = $ip.":".$port;
     $OID = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.19865.1.2.1.{$relenr}.0";
     if(snmpset($adress, $community, $OID, 'i', intval($status))== true)
     {
     echo "\n succes!";
     }
     else
     {
     echo "\n error!!";
     }

  }
?>
```

Comment: Can you provide extra error detail see http://php.net/manual/en/class.snmp.php#snmp.props.exceptions-enabled  Also what happens when you do the equivalent net-snmp snmpset on command line? And the snmpget too ?

Comment: with comman line:

`snmpset -v1 -c private localhost:10161 .1.3.6.1.4.1.19865.1.2.1.10.0 i 1

SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.19865.1.2.1.10.0 = INTEGER: 1`

Answer (score 0):

try this, its working for me:

```
$host = "x.x.x.x:y" ;
$community = "private" ;
$oid = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.19865.1.2.2.1.0" ;
$type = "i" ;
$value = 1 ;
if(snmpset($host, $community, $oid , $type , $value)){
    echo "ok";
}
else{
    echo "error";
}
```

also you can try do it with exec function:

```
exec('snmpset -v1 -cprivate x.x.x.x:y .1.3.6.1.4.1.19865.1.2.2.1.0 i 1',$output,$exitCode);
print_r($output);//print the result
echo $exitCode;//check if the snmpset return 0 == ok
```